# Click to Hover for WMSGetFeatureInfo

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, popup

I am using the following code and wanted to know how I can change it from click event to hover or mousemove event. I know there is a eventListner but I am unable to locate the click event where I must change it to mousemove event.

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/iPlant/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible: true,
            eventListeners: {
                getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                    map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "chicken", 
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                        null,
                        event.text,
                        null,
                        true
                    ));
                }
            }
        });
        map.addControl(info);
        info.activate();
```

**Update 2.0**

I made the changes and also added the PopUp, but only the click function is being recognized.

```
info = {
            click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url : 'http://niles.iplantcollaborative.org:8080/geoserver/wms',
            title : 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible : true,
            eventListeners : {
            getfeatureinfo : function(event) {
            deletePopUp();
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popInfo", map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy), null, event.text, null, true);
            map.addPopup(popup);}}
            }),
            hover: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url : 'http://niles.iplantcollaborative.org:8080/geoserver/wms',
            title : 'Identify features by clicking',
            queryVisible : true,
                    hover : true,
            eventListeners : {
            getfeatureinfo : function(event) {
            deletePopUp();
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popInfo", map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy), null, event.text, null, true);
            map.addPopup(popup);
            }}
            })
            };
            map.addControl(info.hover);
            info.hover.activate();
```

Comment: Oh got it just needed to add `hover : true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add your code in object and then call whatever you want as following code..
actually OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo has hover properties which enough for to solve your problem.

```
       info = {
        click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            layers: [layer],
            queryVisible: true
        }),
        hover: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
            url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
            title: 'Identify features by clicking',
            layers: [layer],
            hover: true,                
            formatOptions: {
                typeName: 'water_bodies', 
                featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/topp'
            },
            queryVisible: true
        })
    };
     map.addControl(info.hover);
     info.hover.activate();
```

> hover
>
> {Boolean} Send GetFeatureInfo requests when mouse stops moving. 
>   Default is false.

i hope it helps you..

Comment: I updated the code, not able to created a PopUp on hover but on click